# Angular 11 aplication and .NET core 3.1 containerized in Docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to generate a docker image for a with .net core 3.1 and Angular 11 application and I'm receiving **The command "npm install" exited with code 127.**

error detail, when I execute the docker file command:

```
 /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmpeb0bf93c7c594a7c89e5fdbd368228c5.exec.cmd: npm: not found
/.csproj(75,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Docker file, cleaned to see more easy:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#Install node in the linux container
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq



#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["project.csproj", "Presentation/Client/Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

csproj project (it's default create by visual studio:

```
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">

    
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Please do not post images of your error messages or configuration files. Please use the coding tags to paste your stuff in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Your dockerfile is missing these instructions.

```
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Node is not installed in the **build and publish stage** but it installed in the **base stage** and included in the **final stage**. That is not the correct way. Node is need to build and publish the application. So it should be installed in the **build and publish stages**.

Remove the line that install Node from the base stage and place it in the build stage:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk AS build

#Install node in the linux container
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq

WORKDIR /src
```

The **publish stage** started from **build stage**, So it includes the Node. So we do not need to install Node in the **publish stage** because it is inherited from **build stage**.

see also this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71980099/17071589)